# how to retrieve events in recurring series using outlook calendar api 2.0?

Tags: node.js, outlook-restapi

I've been using the [node-outlook](https://github.com/jasonjoh/node-outlook) wrapper for the [Outlook Calendar REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#get-events). Currently, when I make a request, I can retrieve one-time events and a series master for recurring events (but not individual events that are apart of the recurring series). How do I modify my query parameters to retrieve a list of events **and** single events which are apart of a recurring series?

```
const queryParams = {
  '$select': 'Subject,Start,End,Location,Type',
  '$orderby': 'Start/DateTime desc',
  '$filter': "Start/DateTime ge '" + start_utc + "' and Start/DateTime le '" + end_utc + "'"
};
```

My goal is to make 1 API request that retrieves all events within the upcoming 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

I belive what you are looking for is `CalendarView`. It's documented [here] [1]

1: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#GetCalendarView

Answer (score 0):

GET request for `CalendarView`:

`https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/<your_meeting_room_id>/calendarview?startDateTime=2019-03-01T00:01:00&endDateTime=2019-03-01T23:59:00`

where `<your_meeting_room_id>` is email of meeting room.